# Python default 'wildcard' function - possible?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my class code:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parameter1 = 1
    
    def standardFunction(self):
        print("Hello")
```

Is it possible to initialise the `Example` class and make sure that every method that may be called for this particular instance will always point to the `standardFunction`?

For example:

```
ex1 = Example()
ex1.test1()
```

prints "Hello"

```
ex1.test2()
```

prints "Hello"

```
ex1.test3.test4()
```

prints "Hello"

```
ex1.test5().test6().IamBatman(42)
```

prints "Hello"

Basically, I would like to always have the `Example.standardFunction()` called, disregarding the string after the first "dot". Plus I don't know what's being put after the dot - it may be any string, int, float, or null.

Is it possible to achieve such behaviour with Python?

Comment: You can implement `__getattr__` for arbitrary attribute access, but the names still have to be valid identifiers for dot notation to work.

Comment: "Plus I don't know what's being put after the dot - it may be any string, int, float, or null." That doesn't make *any* sense. What is "put after the dot" is a *valid identifier*, i.e. it is *source code*. It isn't an object with a type.  with an int, `Example.123` is a syntax error, even with a string, `Example."123"` is a syntax error

Comment: Note, `ex1.test3.test4()` would only be possible if `standardFunction` returns `self`

Comment: Thanks guys, this solves my problem. By saying 'I don't know what goes after the dot' - I meant it could be really anything - I'm trying to mimic a behaviour of another module (that is not maintained by me and is broken). I can't predict how other people are going to call this class... I know it's not perfect, but that's life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can achieve similar behavior in Python by overloading `__getattr__`. Like this,

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parameter1 = 1
    
    def standardFunction(self):
        print("Hello")

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.standardFunction
```